# 2x 1 to (zero or 1) relationships in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I have been facing a problem where I cannot seem to make 1 to 0 or 1 relationships using OLEDB commands and SQL. As shown in this picture, I want to create this kind of relationship:
[image]

I have created this in SQL by:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
TAQID AutoIncrement PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
SourceAID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (SourceAID) REFERENCES Table_SourceA(SourceAID),
InformationIndependantToA STRING
)

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
TBID AutoIncrement PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
SourceB STRING
)

CREATE TABLE Question
(
QID AutoIncrement PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
TAQID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (TAQID) REFERENCES TableA(TAQID),
TBQID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (TBQID) REFERENCES TableB(TBQID),
Question STRING,
MaximumMarkAvaliable INTEGER,
QuestionFileName STRING,
AnswerFileName STRING,
AdditionalNotes TEXT DEFAULT N/A
)

CREATE TABLE Marking
(
MarkID AutoIncrement PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
UserEmailAddress STRING,
FOREIGN KEY (UserEmailAddress) REFERENCES Table_UserDetails(EmailAddress),
QID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (QID) REFERENCES Question(QID),
AnswerDateTime DATETIME,
UserAnswer TEXT,
MarkAwarded INTEGER
)
```

However this creates 1 to many relationships between the Table A and Question and Table B and Question. I want to create 1 to zero or 1 relationships as one table from Table A/Table B isn't being used in every record of question so it would be a 1 to zero relationship while the table being used would be 1 to 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is a `0 to 1` relationship, and how would it work?

Comment: Its dependent on the situation of the record. So if there is a 1 to 1 relationship with one table then a 1 to 0 relationship would make it so that this field can be left null while the whole arrangement is still normalized correctly.

Comment: So, it's a `NULLABLE` column?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to model the situation correctly so that it doesn't violate any normal form conditions. I've been researching 1 to (zero or 1) relationships and they seem to comply with what I need. I'm just not sure on how to implement one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need two nullable FK columns in your Question table, I think.
One pointing to TableA and the other one to TableB.

Comment: But I've been looking on other questions on Stack Overflow and they say that having a nullable FK column violates 5NF.

Comment: @user2177940 And so what? It can be done, I've seen it done on several occasions. I mean, keeping your DB up to the highest theoretical standards is not always the best option. It's a matter of choice after all.

Comment: So its fine to leave one of the foreign keys null in a situation where it is not needed?

Comment: @user2177940 NULL will indicate that it points to no record i.e. the 0 in your "1 or 0" case. And when it has a non-NULL value, it is the 1 in your "1 or 0" case i.e. it points to one record. I find this OK.

Comment: @user2177940 If you want to avoid this, just model it as an M:N relation i.e. use a join table TableJoinA (Question ID, TableA ID). And just put the necessary constraints or triggers on your join table TableJoinA  (to allow holding max 1 row for each given Question ID).

Comment: There is nothing wrong, in my opinion, with a FK field being NULLABLE. If you want to avoid that, you could an 'exception' record in the table(s) that are equivalent to being NULL.

Comment: Yes, I don't find anything wrong either. Actually I think it's one of the options in many DB systems (i.e. the strategy to follow when you delete/update a row but others are pointing to it). For a reference see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066%28v=sql.105%29. Look for: "ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT }"; "ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT }".